# Check string in excel cell for specific content

Tags: excel, string, formatting, conditional-statements, cell

I need to check if an excel cell e.g. "Test123321_E_80" contains "_E_80" how can I do that in excel?
I know it must work with Conditional formatting but I don't know the settings.

Comment: Use `ISNUMBER()` with `SEARCH()` Function. So `SEARCH()` function returns the number of the character at which specific text string is found first, reading left to right and not case sensitive next, wrap it within `ISNUMBER()` Function to return TRUE for a number and FALSE if not found.

Comment: So that said, you can use a formula in conditional formatting like, `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_E_80",A2))` assuming the text string "Test123321_E_80" is in cell `A2`